# Corona SDK - How do we connect external functions to main.lua?

Tags: function, mobile, lua, coronasdk

Right now we have all our code gathered in main.lua. We don't want to work with object oriented code, but still find an easy way of splitting the different objects up into separated files.

In our main.lua file we have objects like water, boat, boy, island and cloud - all together creating one massive bit of code. We want to have "BEGIN WATER 3" in it's own lua file and be able to execute that code in main.lua with a simple function instead. How do we do that?

Here an example from our main.lua file, displaying "water3":

```
--------------- BEGIN WATER 3 ---------------------------------------------------------

local watere = display.newImage( "water3.png", true )
game:insert( watere )
watere.y = 619
watere.x = 500
watere.xScale = 2

--water sound
local wavesound5 = media.newEventSound("waves.wav")

local function playWave5 (event)
  media.playEventSound(wavesound5)
end

local w,h = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight

local function callbackFunc()
  print( "Transition 1 completed" )
end

local function mainwater(watere)
end

function loopar()
  local myTween = transition.to(watere, {time=2300, x=(400), y=(h-140), transition=easing.inOutQuad, onComplete=loopar2})
end

function loopar2()
  local myTween = transition.to(watere, {time=2200, x=(w-500), y=(h-120), transition=easing.inOutQuad, onComplete=loopar})
end

local listener2 = function()
  print( "Transition 2 completed" )
end

local myTween = transition.to(watere, {time=2300, x=(w-400), y=(h-140), transition=easing.inOutQuad, onComplete=loopar})

watere:addEventListener("touch", playWave5)

---------------- END WATER 3 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this other answer I'll try to implement what I think you want. Keep in mind that I have never used CoronaSDK, so it might need some debugging.

First, here's a file called create.lua . You should place it on the same directory as main.lua.

The main objective of `create.lua` is building a table called `create`. That table only has one function for creating water; you can add more functions later, for example for creating ground.

```
-- file 'create.lua'

local function water(game,x,y,xScale,imagePath,soundPath)

  local image = display.newImage( imagePath )
  game:insert( image )

  image.x, image.y, image.xScale = x, y, xScale

  local w,h = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight

  -- create two empty local variables and assign functions to them
  local loopar, loopar2
  loopar = function() transition.to(image, {time=2300, x=(400), y=(h-140), transition=easing.inOutQuad, onComplete=loopar2}) end
  loopar2 = function() transition.to(image, {time=2200, x=(w-500), y=(h-120), transition=easing.inOutQuad, onComplete=loopar}) end

  -- start the movement
  transition.to(image, {time=2300, x=(w-400), y=(h-140), transition=easing.inOutQuad, onComplete=loopar})

  local sound = media.newEventSound(soundPath)
  image:addEventListener("touch", function() media.playEventSound(sound) end )
end

local create = { water = water }

return create
```

Inside main.lua, in order to be able to use create.water first you have to get access to that `create` table; you use `require` for that. Like this:

```
-- file 'main.lua'

local create = require 'create'

<put the code for creating the 'game' group here>

create.water(game, 619, 500, 2, "water3.png", "waves.wav")
```

Notice that create.water receives parameters. You can change the parameters more easily now:

```
create.water(game, 200, 100, 2, "water3.png", "waves.wav") -- other initial coordinates
create.water(game, 619, 500, 1, "water3.png", "waves.wav") -- scaleX = 1
create.water(game, 619, 500, 1, "water.png", "waves.wav") -- other water img
```

Regards!

Comment: This method appears to work without module(..., package.seeall) at the top. Currently I use that statement in my modules but I've heard that is bad practice.

Comment: @jhocking It is a bad practice. The module function will be deprecated in the next version of Lua.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please remember to mark your question as "answered" by clicking on the flag near my answer!

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you can use Lua's [require](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) function in Corona.

The simplest way to use it is the following:

1) You create as many local functions as you want inside the file (let's call it extra.lua)

```
local function f1(...)
  ...
end

local function f2(...)
  ...
end
```

2) After the functions, you build a table that has all the functions you want to "share". It's common that that table is called like the file, so I'll call mine `extras`:

```
local extras = {
  f1 = f1,
  f2 = f2
}
```

This notation might seem weird. What it's doing is creating a table called `extras` with a field called `f1` inside it, pointing to the local function `f1`. In other words, calling `f1(1,2,3)` does the same as calling `extras.f1(1,2,3)`

3) Return the table at the end of the file:

```
return extras
```

4) Now on `main.lua` you can use the functions defined on extras like this:

```
local extras = require 'extras'

extras.f1(1,2,3)
extras.f2(4,5,6)
```

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to create one main function, covering all functions like in "water3", without having to call each single function manually?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "covering"

Comment: Collecting is a better word for what I mean!

Comment: I have similiar problems, my only question is what's happening in step two where you first create the code f1=f1, f2=f2, but then there is something like, extras.f1(1,2,3) i don't understand the connection between the two really.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes. It's absolutely possible to create functions inside another function. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes! We want a function that is encapsulating the other functions, such as the ones you can find in "water3". As for "water3" we would want to put all it's functions in a "box", which we call (for example) water. In main.lua, we now can call for water and all the functions inside water follow along.

Comment: @David It's not only `f1=f1`. The parts above and below are important. I'm creating a table called `extras` with f1 and f2 inside. But instead of putting them on `extras[1]` and `extras[2]`. I'm putting them inside `extras['f1']` and `extras['f2']`. Which are longer versions of `extras.f1` and `extras.f2` respectively.

Comment: @sandra Ok, I'll tell you what. I'll implement what I think you need on another answer.